# Automatic Resolving from Castle Winsdor

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Im trying to seperate my Model,View and ViewModel in different assemblys and instantiate them with Castle Windsor.

I have my app.config

```
<components>
  <component id="ViewModel.SomeViewModel" service="TEST.Business.IViewModel, TEST.Business" type="TEST.ViewModel.SomeViewModel, Test.ViewModel" />
  <component id="ViewModel.SomeView" service="TEST.Business.IView, TEST.Business" type="TEST.View.SomeView, Test.View" />
</components>
```

and resolve it by

```
IoC.Configure(); 
var viewModel = IoC.Resolve<IViewModel>();
var view = IoC.Resolve<IView>();
view.ShowDialog();
```

my static IoC class

```
public static class IoC
{
    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    public static void Configure()
    {

        IResource resource = new ConfigResource("castle");
        container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(resource));
    }

    public static TService Resolve<TService>()
    {
        return container.Resolve<TService>();
    }
}
```

really simple until yet.

But i would love to do it like this:

naming have to be like this: I[someName]ViewModel and I[someName]View
and then resolve every component in my app.config thus for each pair of View and ViewModel resolve and associate them.

I guess there are many solutions for my problem but i dont know which keywords to use.

btw: I[someName]ViewModel and View are ofc IViewModels and IViews

Comment: "Really simple"? This does seem a bit over-engineered. You should prefer dependency injection rather than resolving all types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it wrong.

Do not abstract your views and view models. It gives you no benefit. Therefore the problem is an architectural one, not a technical one.

Comment: I guess ill just keept it as before. Just want to learn new things, so i was interested in this kind of special way i described.

Comment: @Lucas keep things simple. If it hurts, it may be for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to iterate over the types in the assemblies you want to resolve. You can use `Classes` for registrations.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // Replace with the assembly you want to resolve for.
var exports = assembly.ExportedTypes;
var viewTypes = exports.Where(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IView).FullName) != null);

foreach (var viewType in viewTypes)
{
    var viewModelType = assembly.GetType(viewType.FullName.Replace("View", "ViewModel"));
    var viewModel = container.Resolve(viewModelType);
    var view = container.Resolve(viewType);
    view.ShowDialog();
}
```

In your example, I can't see any dependency between IViewModel and IView so your code doesn't make sense. If the view model is injected as a parameter of the constructor it will be automatically resolved.

I would not recommend doing this technique. It is probably more complicated than it needs to be. Are you sure you really understand how to use an IoC container/Castle Windsor?

Answer (score 0):

Ioc containers are great once you get used to them. In general you only want to use your container from your main/bootstrapping code of your application. To me it seems you try to make the resolve function for the container static to allow resolving compoents anywhere. This should not be required.

If you are looking for a method to bind views and view models in nice way, take a look at caliburn micro. You can combine this with most Ioc containers, including windsor

Kind regards,

Marwijn.